# EROFS: read-only file system, open when trying to download a file from an S3 bucket with a lambda function

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, stream

I want to be able to download a file from an aws lambda function.
For that I've come up with the following code:

```
export const downloadFile = async (fileType: FileType): Promise<FileEntry> => {
    const writeStream = fs.createWriteStream(path.join(__dirname, fileType.name))
    const readStream = s3Client.getObject({
        Bucket: process.env.FILE_UPLOAD_BUCKET,
        Key: fileType.key
    }).createReadStream()
        
    readStream.pipe(writeStream)

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        writeStream.on('finish', () => {
            writeStream.close()
            resolve({
                filename: fileType.uri,
                contentType: 'application/pdf',
                content: fs.readFileSync(fileType.uri),
                encoding: 'utf8'
            })
        })
        writeStream.on('error', (err) => {
            fs.unlink(fileType.uri, () => { reject(err) })
        })
    })
}
```

However it is not working, since I am getting the following error:

```
"EROFS: read-only file system, open '/var/task/api/controllers/Admin/filename.pdf'"
```

By the way this folder structure is the same I have in the controller I am using for handling this API call